# Upside down orientation not working in iOS6 for UINavigation view and UITabbar view?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I created an app in ios 6 with navigation view.Also I have set all orientation options in the application summary and even used the

```
 -(BOOL) shouldAutoRotate
```

and

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientaion
```

methods in my view controller.when I run my app orientation works fine except upside-down.What should I do to also support upside-down.

I also facing the same problem when I add UITabBar controller.

Please share your ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hai I have found solution for my problem

**Solution:**
 For the app which consist UINavigation controller, just I created  a category for UINavigation Controller class and I defined these methods

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

After adding this, all orientation were supported in my app.

The same, I done for UITabBar Controller also.This too worked for me by creating category for UITabBar Controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Phone apps traditionally don't support upside down (why would you hold the phone upside down?) - the default project will support portrait and both landscape options, but not upside down.

Change this in the project info viewer in Xcode and you should be fine. There is a visual representation of the supported orientations, and upside down will be unselected.

Comment: Ya you are correct.But my question is,is it possible to support upside-down in app which consist of UINavigation Controller?

Comment: Yeah you can. Take a look a the @Venkatesh answer. You just need to add a category for UINavigationController and that's it.

Comment: UPSideDown makes user easy to access device when device is connected to the data cable. Isn't it?

Comment: if we dont hold the iphone upside down why would apple gave us that option for?

Comment: I didn't say you never hold it upside down, I said the default app template doesn't support upside down orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution of NSUserDefault is incomplete:

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html

> Note: You should always prefer subclassing to categories when
>   modifying rotation behavior for UIKit classes such as
>   UINavigationController. Because other classes may depend on the
>   existing behavior of the UIKit container view controllers, the changes
>   introduced by a category may cause unexpected behavior.

So I think the best solution is to create a subclass and to add:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
     return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{

     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```