# upSideDown iPhone orientation is not working in iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

hope you will be fine and doing your best.

I am getting a problem in `upSideDown Orientation` in my `iOS 6`, while I think I am doing everything perfect, but I don't know why it is not working for me. I am sharing my problem with you so to get any solutions.

What I have done so far:

**a)** In xcode project Summary tab, I have enabled all the 4 orientations.

**b)** I have added piece of code (written below) in all of my controller classes.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

but still the `upSideDown Orientation` is not working

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 8):

I have found its solution.

We need to make a separate class of `UINavigation Controller` type. In `.m` file add the following methods

```
// Deprecated in iOS6, still needed for iOS5 support.
// ---

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return YES;
}

// iOS6 support
// ---
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**Now** assign this newly created class to your `Navigation Controller` in story board. Also add the `.m` file of this class in 'Project -> Build Setting -> Compile Sources'. Run the project and it will support and perform all the orientations including `upSideDown`.

I hope it will help you all.

Regards

Comment: An alternative is to create a category on `UINavigationController` as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16052448/211292

Comment: I need it only for iPhone with iOS 7 to detect PortraitOrientationUpSideDown.